# How to subscribe to journals so that I regularly receive only the Titles and Abstracts without necessarily the full content of the papers?

Tags: journals

How can one subscribe to a non-open access journal such as "Nature Reviews Drug Discovery".
The subscription will be to have the abstract of the latest releases.

Answer (score 2):

For a full-fledged subscription with access to all articles, look for the 'Subscription' section of the website: https://www.nature.com/nrd/subscribe. Usually, researchers are affiliated at a research institution so that they can get access to the journals through their institutional subscriptions (usually through university libraries).

However, it seems that you would be content with the headlines and abstracts of the latest articles of that journal. I see at least five possibilities for you to stay up-to-date with that journal *Nature Reviews Drug Discovery*:

- Regularly visit the journal's website.
- Register for their e-mail
  alerts ([through this link](https://idp.nature.com/register/natureuser?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.nature.com%2Fmy-account%2Falerts%2Fsubscribe-journal%3Flist-id%3D21%26journal-link%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.nature.com%2Fnrd%2F)).
- Make use of their RSS feed
  ([here](http://feeds.nature.com/nrd/rss/current) - use a RSS reader for this purpose, such as *Feedly*, which you can also use on your mobile phone).
- Follow the journal on Twitter ([here is their account](https://twitter.com/NatRevDrugDisc)).
- Program your own
  app to stay up-to-date with that journal by using the
  (machine-readable) *CrossRef* API (access it with the ISSN of that journal - the
  link would be [this one](https://api.crossref.org/journals/1476-4687)).

Comment: Thank you the second one was the one I needed. Not sure how the last option is working exactly but seems like the ideal one to do for multiple similar journals.

Comment: One example that uses the last point's approach - the one via CrossRef's API - is https://ooir.org/ (OOIR). Click on "About", then "Data" to see an explanation of how they do it.